# Event logger won't start: error 2 The system cannot find the file specified, Windows server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service, windows-event-log

**NOTE:** this is a "spawn" of a [previous post](https://serverfault.com/questions/596991/windows-2008-r2-services-not-working) which dealt with 2 different issues and became too lengthy, so I decided to clean the original question and post this issue in a separate question

When I try to start Windows Event Log via `net start eventlog` or via `Services panel`, I get an error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net start eventlog
The Windows Event Log service is starting.
The Windows Event Log service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried the [following advice I from here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-event-log-service-not-starting):

1. restarted the OS (virtual on the host's VMWare).
2. re-checked the settings in services menu -they are like in the link.
3. checked the identity in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\eventlog` - the identity is `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`
4. gave all Authenticated Users full access to `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`
5. ran fc /scannow - Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
6. went to the file `%windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log`  - all clean, [SR] Repairing 0 components

**EDIT:** Uninstalled the recent system updates and rebooted - didn't help

**EDIT:** Sysinternals Process Monitor results when running start service from services panel (procmon in elevated mode):

1. filters:

   ```
   process name is svchost.exe : include
   operation contains TCP : exclude
   ```

   the  events captured are:

   ```
   21:50:33.8105780    svchost.exe 772 Thread Create       SUCCESS Thread ID: 6088
   21:50:33.8108848    svchost.exe 772 RegOpenKey  HKLM    SUCCESS Desired Access: Maximum Allowed, Granted Access: Read
   21:50:33.8109134    svchost.exe 772 RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
   21:50:33.8109302    svchost.exe 772 RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services  REPARSE Desired Access: Read
   21:50:33.8109497    svchost.exe 772 RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
   21:50:33.8110051    svchost.exe 772 RegCloseKey HKLM    SUCCESS 
   21:50:33.8110423    svchost.exe 772 RegQueryKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services  SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
   21:50:33.8110705    svchost.exe 772 RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
   21:50:33.8110923    svchost.exe 772 RegQueryKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
   21:50:33.8111257    svchost.exe 772 RegOpenKey  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
   21:50:33.8111547    svchost.exe 772 RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services  SUCCESS 
   21:50:33.8111752    svchost.exe 772 RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog SUCCESS 
   21:50:33.8111901    svchost.exe 772 RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters\ServiceDll   SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 68, Data: %SystemRoot%\System32\wevtsvc.dll
   21:50:33.8112148    svchost.exe 772 RegCloseKey HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters  SUCCESS 
   21:50:33.8116552    svchost.exe 772 Thread Exit     SUCCESS Thread ID: 6088, User Time: 0.0000000, Kernel Time: 0.0000000
   ```

   **NOTE:** previoulsy,  for

   ```
   21:46:31.6130476    svchost.exe 772 RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters\ServiceDll   SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 68, Data: %SystemRoot%\System32\wevtsvc.dll
   ```

   I also got `NAME NOT FOUND` error ,so I created the new string value for the `Parameters` with the name `ServiceDll` and data `%SystemRoot%\System32\wevtsvc.dll` (copied from the upper `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog` key) and this event now is

   ```
   21:46:31.6130476    svchost.exe 772 RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters\ServiceDll   SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 68, Data: %SystemRoot%\System32\wevtsvc.dll
   ```

   I also checked for the presence of `wevtsvc.dll` in the place and it's there.
2. Also, I tried to capture all events with path containing `'event'` and got following events firing every several seconds:

   ```
   21:38:38.9185226    services.exe    492 RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\EventSystem\Tag  NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 16
   21:38:38.9185513    services.exe    492 RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\EventSystem\DependOnGroup    NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 268
   21:38:38.9185938    services.exe    492 RegQueryValue   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\EventSystem\Group    NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 268
   ```
3. Also, I tried to capture all the events containing `'file'`, excluding `w3wp.exe, chrome.exe, wmiprvse.exe, wmtoolsd.exe, System` and it shows **NO** attempts to access any file ih the time I try to start the event logger  (if run from cmd - there are several hits by `net` executable, not present if run from the panel).

**EDIT**: the event logging stopped working on 04/May/2014 at 03:15.

The only change that day was `security update 2964444` - `Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows Server 2008 R2for x64-based Systems`, that was installed exactly 04/May/2014 at 03:00. Apparently, that's what broke my machine...

What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the problem was to delete the

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Parameters\
```

key.

As I stated earlier, I've seen this error with Process Monitor, but chose to put there some key - and that was my mistake. I should've delete this key instead.

Comment: This also fixes the same problem on Windows server 2012 R2.